# Python regex replace whole string

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to strip the end off a request url:

```
re.sub('(?:^\/en\/category).*(-\d{1,4}$)', '', r)
```

My problem is that the docs say it will replace the matched part, however when it matches my string it replaces the **whole string**, e.g.:

```
/en/category/specials/men-2610
```

I'm not sure what Python is doing, but [my regex seems fine](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1pU2/1)

*EDIT*: I wish to have the string with the end stripped off, target =

```
/en/category/specials/men
```

Comment: define your pattern as raw string.

Comment: yep, it replaces the whole string because the whole string is matched.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: what do you want to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the docs, the **matched part** is replaced. **Matched** is different from **captured**.

You will have to capture the text you *don't* want to remove in a capture group like so:

```
(^/en/category.*)-\d{1,4}$
```

and put it back into the string using the backreference `\1`:

```
re.sub(r'(^/en/category.*)-\d{1,4}$', r'\1', text)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about matched vs captured. I was not aware of how it was handled.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=^\/en\/category)(.*)-\d{1,4}$
```

Try this.replace by `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/27

Your whole pattern matches that is why it is replacing the whole string.

P.S `match` is different than `captures or groups`.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=^\/en\/category)(.*)-\d{1,4}$', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "/en/category/specials/men-2610"
subst = "\1"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just transfer the capturing group to the other part and then replace the match with `\1` and you don't need to escape the forward slash if the pattern is defined as a raw string.

```
re.sub(r'^(/en/category.*)-\d{1,4}$', r'\1', string)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1pU2/2)

```
>>> s = "/en/category/specials/men-2610"
>>> re.sub(r'^(/en/category.*)-\d{1,4}$', r'\1', s)
'/en/category/specials/men'
```

OR

```
>>> s.split('-')[0]
'/en/category/specials/men'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.sub('(^\/en\/category.*)(-\d{1,4}$)', 
           r'\1', '/en/category/specials/men-2610')
'/en/category/specials/men'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is fine, you just need to change which item is the capturing group:

Before:

```
(?:^\/en\/category).*(-\d{1,4}$)
```

After:

```
((?:^\\/en\\/category).*)-\\d{1,4}$
```

Since the `?:` is no longer necessary we can reduce this further to:

```
(^\\/en\\/category.*)-\\d{1,4}$
```

Notice I've moved the capturing group from the digits to the part before it.

Example:

http://ideone.com/FLAaFh